# How to change the base of NumPy logistic function?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, statistics

For an Elo rating system simulation, I would need to draw samples from a logistic distribution in base sqrt(10).

On the NumPy documentation, I have found :
https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.random.logistic.html
This use the probabity density in base "e":

```
exp((loc-x)/scale)/(scale*(1+exp((loc-x)/scale))**2)
```

I would need to use the probability density in base sqrt(10).
Do you have any idea how I could do that ?

Comment: Would need someone better at statistics to check it, but I think you'd just take the [quantile function of the Logistic Distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_distribution), change the `ln` to base `sqrt(10)` and set `p` to `np.random.rand`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After checking a bit I'm fairly confident this is correct mathematically:

```
def logistic_sample(n, loc = 0, scale = 1, base = np.exp(1)):
    p = np.random.rand(n)
    return loc + scale * np.log(p / (1 - p)) / np.log(base)
```

Other possibility is to create a new `scipy.stats.rv_continuous` class if you really need to dig into that distribution:

```
class logistic_base_gen(scipy.stats.rv_continuous):
    def _pdf(self, x, loc, scale, base):
        return base ** ((loc - x) / scale) / (s * (1 + base ** ((loc - x) / scale)) ** 2)

logistic_base = logistic_base_gen(0)
logistic_base.rvs(loc, scale, np.sqrt(10), size = n)
```